# Transaction Interceptor CDI JPA JavaSE

Tags: jpa, cdi, interceptor, transactional

I made an interceptor transactions for my DAOs using CDI. However, the EntityManager that is injected into the DAO, is not the same used in the transaction interceptor. How can I do to use the same EntityManager?

**DAO Class**

```
public class GenericDAO<T, PK> {

    public final EntityManager manager;

    public GenericDAO(EntityManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    @Transactional
    public T getById(PK pk) {
        Object o = manager.find(getTypeClass(), (Serializable) pk);
        return (T) o;
    }
}
```

**EntityManager Producer:**

```
public class EntityManagerProducer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Produces
    public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("bd").createEntityManager();
    }

    public void closeEntityManager(@Disposes EntityManager manager) {
        if (manager.isOpen()) {
            manager.close();
            System.out.println("CLOSE ENTITY MANAGER !!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

I see that it is created twice because the print on Method closeEntityManager is invoked twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your producer method has `@Dependent` scope, it will produce a new `EntityManager` instance for each injection point.

By the way, rather than rolling your own transactional interceptor, you might want to check out [DeltaSpike](http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jpa.html) (JPA and Data modules).

Comment: Many thanks for the tip. I read a lot about DeltaSpike, I think that will do nicely for my purpose.
With it, the problem two entityManager be injected will be solved, right?